# Force and lions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, sun, estimation

Alright. So me and some other people right now need an answer to this. If you have 1 trillion lions traveling at 81 kilometers (top speed of a lion) towards the Sun in a pretty dense ball. (As dense a ball as 1 trillion lions can get) what kind of damage will it do to the sun?

Comment: The lions would collapse into some sort of strange star that has an unusual balance of hydrogen, carbon, and oxygen.  Our own sun would rapidly accelerate towards the lion star.

Comment: Relevant What if xkcd: [A Mole of Moles](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/). This is pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: Also xkcd, the starlings star: https://what-if.xkcd.com/99/

Comment: @BrandonEnright: This would be a good answer, but short trillion is $10^{12}$ and even long trillion is only $10^{18}$. According to Wikipedia, average male lion from South Africa weights about 190 kg ([189.6 kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion)). $1.9 \cdot 10^{14}$ kg is less than comet 118401 LINEAR $2.3 \cdot 10^{14}$ kg and $1.9 \cdot 10^{20}$ kg is probably less than planetoid Pallas $2.11 \pm 0.26 \cdot 10^{20}$ kg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mass of Sun = $1.989 \times 10^{30} \text{ kg}$.

Mass of 1 lion = $190 \text{ kg}$.

Mass of 1 lion in spacesuit = $250\text{ kg}$.

Mass of 1 trillion lions = $190 \times 10^{12} \text{ kg}$.

Mass of 1 trillion lions in spacesuit = $250 \times 10^{12} \text{ kg}$.

Mass of 1 trillion pregnant lioness in spacesuit = $300 \times 10^{12} \text{ kg}$.

Temperature of Sun's surface = 5778 K.

Any objects would instantly disintegrated at close proximity, probably less than 50 yards.

Speed of lion is 81 km/h or 22.5 m/s.

Kinetic energy of 1 trillion pregnant lioness in spacesuit = $0.5 \times (3 \times 10^{14} \text{ kg}) \times (22.5 \text{ m/s})^2
= 7.59375 \times 10^{16}$ J.

Fact: Yearly electricity consumption in Mongolia as of 2010 is $1.1 × 10^{16}$ J.

Distance from impact = 10000 m (assumption).

Time from impact is (10000 m) / (22.5 m/s) = 444.444 s

New Time from impact changed to 1 s (sorry 444.444 s takes too long to barbecue the animal)

Power of 1 trillion pregnant lioness in spacesuit $= 7.59375 \times 10^{16} \text{ J} /\text{ s} =7.59375 \times 10^{16} \text{ W}$.

Fact: luminosity of the Sun is $3.846 \times 10^{26} $ W.

---

**NEW**

Tidal acceleration "a" across a body with specific length is as follows:

Acceleration of gravity on Sun's surface = 274 m/s^2.

Mass of Sun = $1.989 \times 10^30 kg$.

Radius of Sun = 695800000 m.

Constant of gravity = 6.67 x 10^-8 dynes cm^2/gm^2.

a = (2 x (6.67 x 10^-8 dynes cm^2/gm^2) x (1.989 x 10^30 Kg) x d) /  (695800000 m)^3

Alright people don't assume I can do this! now you only need to substitute variable "d" with the diameter of your meatball of lions to find out the tidal acceleration across the length. (are you expecting spaghettification to occur!)

---

Conclusion: For committing animal abuse you shall be sentenced to infinite levels of hell where-ever that is, P.S. Sun still remains.

Kindly check my calculation, I don't have a science degree! or a calculator so doing it mentally.

Comment: If you're expecting a black hole look elsewhere, the Sun won't even bulge a bit if Earth drop by. Unless you want a living planet from hell orbiting the Sun, my god you're evil.

Comment: I am a huge fan of "no calculator" calculations!